# problem in inserting the value in the database

Tags: java, android, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi i am developing the android application. I am using sql server 2008 R2 database to store the data and retrieve the data. Now when i am inserting the value in the database i am inserting 4 dates in the table.

Here is the query:

```
"INSERT Into Task_Master VALUES ('1'," +
                "" +userId+"," +userId+ ",'N','" +Subject+ "'," +
                "'" + serverdate + "','" + StartDate+ "','" + serverdate + "'," +
                "'"+" "+"'," +
                "'" +" "+ "','0'," +groupId+ ",0,0,1,0,'1/1/1900','','N','" +cal.getTime()+ "','')" +
                " Select Scope_Identity()";
```

In that "Serverdate" , StartDate,Cal.getTime() all have data type Date. And in database i have used the datetime data type. But still it gives me Exception which says "java.sql.sqlexception:Conversion failed when converting date or/and time from character string ". Do help me if you know the answer. I searched in googlwe but haven't got the answer.

Comment: could you provide your table schema?

Comment: Use preparedStatement to save yourself time bruv.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, let's do this.

First, and most important of all, your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should work on that and start using parameters.

Second, by the time you start using parameters, your error will most likely disappear (or reappear somewhere else, this time clearer on what's wrong). That's because, probably, the server "doesn't like" your [stringly typed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349378/new-programming-jargon-you-coined/2444303#2444303) date format, so it fails.

**Update**

About parameterized queries in java, read here:

- https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Preventing_SQL_Injection_in_Java
- http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html
- http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html
- http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2007/jw-04-jdbc.html

Comment: parameter means? I didn't get you.

Comment: hey i have used preparedStatement. but wen i am executing ps.executeUpdate() it gives me exception like "The executeUpdate method must not return a result set"

Answer (score 0):

I would guess there's a date format mismatch.

Try looking here: http://www.coderanch.com/t/385771/java/java/java-sql-Date-dd-mm