# Safe user input

Tags: android, sql, xml, sql-injection

I have read many forum (and stack overflow) posts regarding escaping characters and sanitizing user input, but I'd like to tie it all together and make it a little more specific to the Android platform. Here's my circumstance:

I have an Android app that communicates with a web service via SOAP XML messages. Here's a sample XML message that might be sent (I'm leaving out the SOAP envelope around it):

```
<Log>
    <Summary>user entered text</Summary>
    <Details>user entered text</Details>
</Log>
```

As you can see, there are 2 places a user can input text in a form that is then inserted into this message to be sent to the web service. I need to:
A) make sure it's valid XML and
B) make sure it doesn't contain any malicious SQL content.

Are there any pre-included utilities in the Android API to escape invalid XML chars (such as &) that the user may have entered? (So that I can simply say "escapeXML(xmlstring);" or something like that)

Is there any way to check for malicious SQL (or other code injection) or should that be handled on the server-side?

As a side note: I'd almost prefer that the user was only able to enter A-z, 0-9 and basic punctuation (so as to avoid weird unicode characters that can't even be seen or interpreted sometimes). Is there a good way to restrict user input to a subset of characters?

I know this is a couple questions built into one, so if you only know part of it, please provide an answer anyways and I will be more than happy to upvote or accept it. Thanks in advance for all the help! (StackOverflow is where I come when I've consumed way too many forum threads and have gotten myself all twisted around about what is appropriate in my circumstance)

Comment: I guess you could probably restrict it with regex, but I wouldn't.  First off, restricting it that way won't at all protect against injection (all you need is basic puctuation).  Second, if any of your users is using a foreign character set (or even attempting to _correctly_ input foreign loan-words), the may be a bit miffed if their input is being refused.  Normally you shouldn't store formatted XML - store entities (class instances) instead.  Parameterized queries should take care of SQL injection - you're going to need to watch out for cross-site-scripting here, too.

Comment: Well I know we won't be dealing with the issue of foreign words since it is an app that is custom written for a specific client that only does work in the US. Also, I wasn't thinking that restricting input to text, numbers, and punctuation would prevent the SQL injection but rather it would keep the text reader-friendly (since the mind doesn't know how to "read" a Control character for example)

Comment: Without knowing your client, I can't say for certain, but you may be using foreign words more often than you realize (even if you're not 'spelling' them properly).  Even if your client only works in the US (more so depending on domain/location).  Normally when dealing with SOAP, you're using some framework/library that is serializing/deserializing the message - your code doesn't necessarily even know that it came from an XML message (and probably shouldn't).  There are several for Java, don't know about an Android-specific version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to deal with [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) is using parameterized queries. This is done on the server side. Everything else is secondary, unnecessary or barely scratches the surface of the issue.

You should read these:

- [Safe DateTime in a T-SQL INSERT statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7500391/safe-datetime-in-a-t-sql-insert-statement/7500402#7500402)
- [problem in inserting the value in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486280/problem-in-inserting-the-value-in-the-database/7486382#7486382)
- http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html

On Jeff Atwood's blog, I like where he says:

> Non-parameterized SQL is the GoTo statement of database programming.

Comment: As an avid GoTo hater myself, I can definitely appreciate that and will look into what we can do server side (the web services are connected to an IBM Maximo asset management system so I may be limited or it may already do it for us)